# captar onClick con if else

Tags: jquery

Tengo este JQuery (gracias a la ayuda de un compañero de aquí) en el que al hacer scroll hacia arriba me aparece la cabecera y al hacerlo hacia abajo me desaparece.

La cosa es que quiero que al hacer click en cierto enlace **también aparezca** , pero mi todavía ignorancia no lo consigue sacar.

¿Como capto el click en el enlace? Mi intención es que tanto si se hace ese click o si se hace scroll hacia arriba, aparezca la cabecera.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var lastScrollTop = 0;

  $(window).scroll(function(event) {

    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (st < lastScrollTop || $('#Conoceme').click(function());) {
      document.getElementById("Cabecera").style.display = "block"
    } else {
      document.getElementById("Cabecera").style.display = "none"
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crearte una función `mostrarCabecera` para mostrar u ocultar la cabecera y que puedas llamar desde los dos controladores de eventos: `scroll` y `click`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  
  function mostrarCabecera(mostrar){
    document.getElementById('Cabecera').style.display =
      mostrar ? 'block' : 'none';
  }

  $(window).scroll(function(event) {

    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    mostrarCabecera(st < lastScrollTop);

    lastScrollTop = st;
  });
  
  $('#Conoceme').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mostrarCabecera(true);
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  padding-top: 400px;
}

#Cabecera{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Cabecera">Cabecera</div>
<a id="Conoceme" href="#">Conóceme</a>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

El código que has puesto recoge el evento del scroll como bien dices. Para saber cuándo hacen click necesitas `.click`. Colócalo antes o después del `$(window).scroll(function(event)`, no dentro.

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  document.getElementById("Cabecera").style.display = "block"
});
```

Sustituye `#target` por el enlace en cuestión que quieras controlar.